# First unused from 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to find first match only once from each column, needed in one line of tsql (no loops or cursors --added after cursor answer--)

```
;WITH TempTable AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),
                          (4,2),(4,3),(5,4)) AS y(pos,MatchingPos)
)
SELECT * FROM TempTable...
```

Results:

```
  1,1 returned
  2,2 returned
  2,3 Not returned: Column 1 Value 2 already returned
  3,2 Not returned: Column 2 Value 2 already returned
  3,3 returned
  4,2 Not returned: Column 2 Value 2 already returned
  4,3 Not returned: Column 2 Value 3 already returned
  5,4 returned
```

Comment: does pos determine the order ?

Comment: ORDER BY pos, MatchingPos: The data will always be in that order.

Comment: what's the sql server version?

Comment: 2008r2 answer is best, but 2012 is better than no 2008r2

Comment: Could I see a larger set of values? I've got a recursive CTE that appears to be working... but I don't trust it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of cursors. But it seems necessary for this:

```
Declare @t table(pos int,MatchingPos int)

Declare @pos int, @MatchingPos int
Declare SqlCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT pos,MatchingPos FROM 
(VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),
                          (4,2),(4,3),(5,4)) AS y(pos,MatchingPos)
OPEN SqlCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
INTO @pos, @MatchingPos
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

insert @t
select @pos, @MatchingPos
where not exists
(select 1 from @t where pos = @pos or @MatchingPos = MatchingPos)
     FETCH NEXT FROM SqlCursor
     INTO @pos, @MatchingPos
END
CLOSE SqlCursor
DEALLOCATE SqlCursor


select * from @t
```

Result:

```
pos MatchingPos
1   1
2   2
3   3
5   4
```

Comment: Thank you, but need to avoid loops & cursors to achieve goals. I am worried you are right that it can't be done avoiding them.

Comment: @Ennui you may need to avoid cursors. But the problem is that you want to compare with rows that have not yet been inserted one by one. So you don't have much choice

Comment: I agree. I was hoping a recursive CTE could do the job, but I haven't been able to come up logic myself.

Comment: @Ennui this issue has been up before. There is no good logic for testing that in a recursive. Only very performance costly methods that stores unaccepted values in a long varchar.

Comment: Thank you, if I could solve this I would take a ~90 minute process to 2 minutes.

Comment: @EarlOfEnnui did you consider a function ?

Answer (score 0):

Alright - this CTE appears to work with the dataset above. It's a bit messy, and the CTE could his max recursion reasonably easily depending on your data.

```
;WITH TempTable AS
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),
                          (4,2),(4,3),(5,4)) AS y(pos,MatchingPos)
), TempTable2 AS
(
    SELECT T1.pos, 
           T1.MatchingPos,
           CASE WHEN min(T2.MatchingPos) < T1.MatchingPos THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Pos_Exists,
           CASE WHEN min(T3.pos) < T1.pos THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as MatchingPos_Exists,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY T1.pos ASC, T1.MatchingPos ASC) RowNum
    FROM TempTable T1
    LEFT JOIN TempTable T2
      ON T1.pos = T2.pos AND T1.MatchingPos != T2.MatchingPos
    LEFT JOIN TempTable T3
      ON T1.MatchingPos = T3.MatchingPos AND T1.pos != T3.pos
    GROUP BY T1.pos, T1.MatchingPos
)
, TempTable3 AS
(
    SELECT pos, MatchingPos, RowNum, 1 AS Included, CAST(0 aS BIGINT) ParentRow
    FROM TempTable2 
    WHERE  Pos_Exists = 0 AND MatchingPos_Exists = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT T1.pos, T1.MatchingPos, T1.RowNum,
        T2.Included - 1 AS Included, 
        CASE WHEN T2.Included = 1 THEN T2.RowNum WHEN T2.Included < 0 THEN T2.RowNum ELSE -1 END as ParentRow
    FROM TempTable2 T1
    JOIN TempTable3 T2
    ON T1.RowNum > T2.RowNum 
      AND (T1.pos = T2.pos OR T1.MatchingPos = T2.MatchingPos)
      AND (T2.ParentRow != 0 OR T2.Included = 1)
)

SELECT pos, MatchingPos FROM TempTable3 
GROUP BY pos, MatchingPos
HAVING MAX(Included) = 1 OR (MAX(ParentRow) = -1)
```

Comment: Looking good so far, thank you. I will update after I put it through some more tests.

Comment: @EarlOfEnnui Sadly, doesn't work, I threw some more data in there and had incorrect results returned. Back to the drawing board.